# shouldn't the Global variable "a" change to be 20 then 30

Tags: r, function

```
a <-70

outer <- function(){
a <<- 20
    inner <- function(){
    a <<- 30
    print(a)
} # end of inner function
inner() 
print(a)

} # end of outer function
```

► Now Printing out the outer function

```
> outer()
   30
   20
> a
  70
```

How could "a" still 70 ... <<- is changing the global variable
in outer "a" is changing the out "a" ... in inner ... "a" is changing the "a" in outer() ... so how could the Most out "a"  still 70 ??

Comment: Something's not right in your example - the inner loop is closed before `inner()` is called and there is one too many closing braces. Evaluating the `outer()` function shouldn't produce two print statements.

Comment: Something is wrong with the question as there is only print statement and there are two printed lines in your output do change it accordingly.. I think it would just print 20 for what you have written currently.

Comment: my fault.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [`reprex()`](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex) for reproducible examples which would show that your braces were misaligned and that the answer is in fact `30`.

```r
a <- 70

outer <- function(){
  a <<- 20
  inner <- function(){
    a <<- 30
    print(a)
  } # end of inner function
  inner() 
  print(a)

} # end of outer function
outer()
#> [1] 30
#> [1] 30
a
#> [1] 30
```